# Iterative Method through FEM

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

Due to reasons, I cannot fully describe the process explicitly so I will be using substitutes to represent the variables.

### Nomenclature:

**x** - an independent variable

**y** - another independent variable

**Fz** - Original force value

**Fz'** - New force value.

*Note: these variables are all vectors. The number of components depend on the number of locations required. For example, a 4-location problem will have $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$.

### Goal:

- Find the value for x that will produce Fz' that's within 100-110% of Fz.
  Each individual Fz' must be within 10% of its respective Fz such as Fz'1 & Fz1
  Often time changing x alone will not produce any results, therefore another variable can be added y to reach convergence of a solution. Such that $Fz' = f(x,y)$

### Constraints

- The value of for $x$ is explicitly defined. A fixed set. example: {55500 44751 321548 ...} - The value for $y$ is within $-100<y<100$ with 1 as the min increments.

### Difficulty

1. Given that the relationships come from an FEA tool though the analysis itself is linearly static, the interactions between the locations and their effects on Fz' may not fit cleanly into a linear matrix framework.
2. The couplings between locations complicates the problem. Such that change x or y or both in location 1 could affect the value for Fz' at other locations.

I was wondering if anyone have an idea on how to tackle this problem. I want to see if there's a mathematical way of solving this. Originally, I wanted to solve this through linear algebra, but the relationship between Fz and $x$ is most definitely nonlinear. The brute force iterative methods would be very computationally expensive.

My goal is to find a way to converge the solution and automate the process with code.

Please let me know what you guys have in mind.

Thank you guys for your help.

-Zhihao Liu

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/-Yp0u0UlnRg

Comment: Thank you Ricky.

Comment: Do you mean that, you have made $n$ times *parameters* (say) $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ set to certain values (resulting in a $4 \times n$ matrix $P$), and *observed* for each of the $n$ experiments, the value of other parameters, say $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, that can be placed in a $3 \times n$ matrix $O$. And you want, out of these 2 arrays $P$ and $O$, define a relationship predicting *observations* as functions of *parameters* ? Maybe, it is a too simplistic view on my side ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Hi Jean. Sorry for the confusing question, I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have a system with multiple locations. For each location, I can adjust a parameter $x$ and a parameter $y$. I am trying to determine the appropriate value of $x$ and 
$y$ values so that the resulting value $Fz'$ from an FEA simulation is within 1-1.1 of the original value $F_z$.  However, adjusting the $x$ parameter or the $y$ parameter at one location can influence the outcomes at other points. I'm looking to optimize the $x$ and $y$ values under the constraints above and interdependencies.

Comment: What is FEM ? Finite Element Method ? Same question for FEA.

Comment: In your recent comment : "I have a system with multiple locations" : sorry, but the words "system" and "locations" are ambiguous. I understand that you want to hide the exact meaning of the words you use, but the result is that you aren't understood.

Comment: @JeanMarie Correct. FEA (Finite Element Analysis). Adjusting the $x$ and $y$ parameters in the Finite Element model will produce a set of $F_z'$ values. Which then I will have to determine whether it's within a 10% range compared to the original $F_z$ values. Typically, it takes a lot of manual iterations: adjusting the parameters. So I was wondering if this is something that can be optimized through mathematics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148556/discussion-between-lone-coder-and-jean-marie).

Comment: Do you mean that your ultimate goal is to adjust vertices of triangles (2D) or thetrahedra (3D) ?